# How to fix 'Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character 0xe2' in Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I am trying to write a basic arm assembly file on my raspberry pi 3 that has access to printf and scanf through the gcc compiler, but upon compiling my code I get a strange error.

This is my third application written in assembly to use the gcc compiler, so I wanted to do incremental testing so I set up my prompts and strings, and I try and exit cleanly; however, this is my code that throws the error:

```
.data
    .balign 4
    promptNum1: .asciz “Please enter some number that you want to work with”
    .balign 4
    inputNum1String: .asciz “%d”
    .balign 4
    outputString: .asciz “Your answer is %d”
    .balign 4
    return: .word 0
    .balign 4
    signPrompt: .word “What do you want the numbers to do?\n 1)add \n 2)subtract\n 3)multiply\n 4)divide”
.text
.global main
main: 
    ldr r11, addressOfReturn
    str lr, [r11]
.
.
.
    ldr r11, addressOfReturn
    ldr lr, [r11]
    bx lr

addressOfPromptNum1: .word promptNum1
addressOfInputNum1String: .word inputNum1String
addressOfOutputString: .word outputString
addressOfReturn: .word return
```

I expect this to compile as my previous code did, however, my error references an unrecognized character on the lines with promptNum1, inputNum1String, outputString, signPrompt. However, the character that is unrecognized is **0xe2**, and upon looking that up I found that the character that is not recognized by the compiler is **not in my file at all.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotes in your code are "smart quotes" (the utf-8 sequences `e2 80 9c` and `e2 80 9d`), which isn't playing well with the assembler. Change them to be regular quotes and you should be fine.

```
.data
    .balign 4
    promptNum1: .asciz "Please enter some number that you want to work with"
    .balign 4
    inputNum1String: .asciz "%d"
    .balign 4
    outputString: .asciz "Your answer is %d"
    .balign 4
    return: .word 0
    .balign 4
    signPrompt: .word "What do you want the numbers to do?\n 1)add \n 2)subtract\n 3)multiply\n 4)divide"
.text
.global main
main: 
    ldr r11, addressOfReturn
    str lr, [r11]
.
.
.
    ldr r11, addressOfReturn
    ldr lr, [r11]
    bx lr

addressOfPromptNum1: .word promptNum1
addressOfInputNum1String: .word inputNum1String
addressOfOutputString: .word outputString
addressOfReturn: .word return
```

Comment: This problem generally indicates that you are using a text editor not meant for programming.  Try to turn off smart quotes in your editor or use a different editor meant for programming work.

Comment: I was using vim for editing the text and I don't think anything is wrong with vim unless some weird plug in caused that.

Comment: Thanks I never would have seen that as it was a different character, I'm pretty sure that I have only been working on the project in vim, and tmux but not sure how those got there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NoahFranck I find this happens a lot when copying stuff off of web pages.  Many sites talking about code also have plugins that convert the author's regular quotes into smart quotes and the authors don't realize that it's happening or just don't know how to fix it.  In fact, it comes up so often that my vim setup has a [ToAscii function](https://github.com/drmikehenry/vimfiles/blob/a9ade3a5c46d8e9c90e9401447aa44be87d13a8f/vimrc#L2531) to help fix these kinds of issues. :-)